# Discovering Smart TVs on my local Network through Android NSD

Tags: android, local-network, network-scan, iptv

I'm developing an Android app that scans the Smart TVs on my local network using Android NSD; at some point, I need to define which kind the service type (protocol + transport layer) NSD looks for, and he only examples I've found are ._http._tcp and ._ipp._tcp (using these examples I find printers and other devices, but not TV); do you know which service I should use to find the TVs?

Answer (score 1):

I was developing an Android app Remote Controller for Samsung Smart TV. For TV discovery i used UPnP protocol libraries provided by Samsung. If it helps you I know that smart TVs are using TCP and HTTP protocols the most for communication with other devices on LAN.

On the official Android developer web site states:

Note: The International Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) manages a centralized, authoritative list of service types used by service discovery protocols such as NSD and Bonjour. You can download the list from the IANA list of service names and port numbers. If you intend to use a new service type, you should reserve it by filling out the IANA Ports and Service registration form.

[http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.htm](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)l

But you have probably read this already.